# How to wrap a background media player in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-mediaplayer

For my application I want to start a [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) which playbacks a remote stream and catches and display events. The media player must keep on playing even if the application moves into the background. Hence, I was under the impression a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is the right choice to wrap the implementation code:

> - A facility for the application to tell the system about something it wants to be doing in the background (even when the user is not
>     directly interacting with the application). This corresponds to calls
>     to Context.startService(), which ask the system to schedule work for
>     the service, to be run until the service or someone else explicitly
>     stop it.
> - A facility for an application to expose some of its functionality to other applications. This corresponds to calls to
>     Context.bindService(), which allows a long-standing connection to be
>     made to the service in order to interact with it.

Since I am **performing blocking tasks** in the service this also blocks the UI Thread which is not acceptable. This faced me with the possibility to either use an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) or delegate the code of `onStartCommand()` into another thread. With `IntentService` I have to invoke `Looper.loop()` at the end of `onHandleIntent()`.

This approach works like a charm but it gives me the impression that this is just a hack and should be done properly. Maybe even without a `Service` or `IntentService` at all. After all I am using the event bus library [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) anyway.